# How do I change the default value of a raddropdownlist from outside the control?

Tags: forms, user-controls, telerik

I have a raddropdown list and need different default values for when it is used in different pages. This is the code for the raddropdown in th user control:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UploadExcel.ascx.cs" Inherits="EntityFramework.Controls.UploadExcel" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" TagPrefix="telerik" %>
<telerik:RadStyleSheetManager ID="RadStyleSheetManager1" runat="server" />
<div style="height: 50px;"></div>
<telerik:RadDropDownList ID="RadDropDownList1" runat="server" Width="200">

<Items>
    <telerik:DropDownListItem  Selected="true" Text="STL010_gen_and_load_settlement" />
    <telerik:DropDownListItem Visible="false" Text="LeasingSolarEdge" />
</Items>
```

I have 2 pages which use this user control and need different values to be selected when the page loads. The page code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="STL010Upload.aspx.cs" Inherits="SunseapEBT.Web.UploadParameter.STL010Upload" %>

<%@ Register Src="~/Control/Upload/UploadExcel.ascx" TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="UploadExcel" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<uc1:UploadExcel runat="server" ID="UploadExcel" />
</asp:Content>
```

Is there any way to change user control values from the page when it loads the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to change it from the user control by getting the url of the page that requested it.

```
 if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("STL010"))
        {
            RadDropDownList1.Enabled = false;
            RadDropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        }
        else if (Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("Solar"))
        {
            RadDropDownList1.Enabled = false;
            RadDropDownList1.SelectedIndex = 1;
        }
```